# Saving a png with photoshop script not working

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

```
if (app.documents.length != 0) {
    var doc= app.activeDocument;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var layer = doc.artLayers[0]
        layer.textItem.contents = i;

        var pngFile    = new File("/Users/dlokshin/temp/" + i + ".png");
        pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
        pngSaveOptions.interlaced = false;
        doc.saveAs(pngFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the script above, instead of saving the files as 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, etc it opens up the save dialogue box and prompts me to type in the file name and click save. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aparently saving a PNG is very different from saving a JPEG when scripting for photoshop. The below works for PNGs:

```
if (app.documents.length != 0) {
    var doc= app.activeDocument;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var layer = doc.artLayers[0]
        layer.textItem.contents = i;

        var opts, file;
        opts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
        opts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
        opts.PNG8 = false;
        opts.quality = 100;

        pngFile = new File("/Users/dlokshin/temp/speed.png");
        app.activeDocument.exportDocument(pngFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, opts);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me - though the most significant difference I have seen since changing my implementation to the one you have provided is that the save (export) of the PNG takes a really long time. Something I'll have to live with, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Saving with `PNGSaveOptions` works for me if I provide Photoshop with the save path like this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;  
var filePath = activeDocument.fullName.path;  
var pngFile = File(filePath + "/" + "myname.png");
pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
doc.saveAs(pngFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
```

Comment: I can confirm that using `PNGSaveOptions` works well for PNG files. It saves the entire file.

Answer (score 1):

Just type this at the beginning

```
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;
```

And you will not get dialogs anymore.

Comment: `app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;` hides the dialog, but script execution then just stops when the dialog would've been shown